# Change the View's background of a ListView initially

Tags: java, android, listview, view, android-arrayadapter

I'm now implementing an application that contains an Activity includes ListView, when the user selects any item in the list view, the background & text color of this view are changed, So, i placed the code of this changes in the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)` method ..but,this is not the problem.

The problem is, when i open the activity, i need to make an initial selection "before the user selects any thing"..so i made `listView.setSelection(index);`, but, unfortunately, this code doesn't invoke the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)`..So, the view doesn't changed "background and text color".

Any solution for that..?!!!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try onItemSelected for selection

selecting a iem in list view does not fires onItemClick

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in yout Adapter to set the selection (or do it in the constructor):

```
public myAdapter (COntext context, int initialSelectedPos){
   setSelectedPos(initialSelectedPos);
}

public void setSelectedPos(int pos){
   mSelectedPos = pos;
}
```

Then check in your getView is given pos is the same than mSelectedPos.

```
@Override
public View getView(..., int pos){
   /*convertView stuff*/

   if (pos == mSelectedPos){
      //Put the background as it is selected
   }else{
      //...
   }

   return view;
}
```

In your OnItemClick method from your OnItemClickListener call the setSelectedPos method of your Adapter. 
You will solve the issue you commented and also when your selected view is no longer visible on screen and comes back to screen, will still be marked as selected ( I am pretty sure it was appearing with the original background).

Answer (score 0):

after setting selection

```
 listView.setSelection(index);
```

and then after call the

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged();
```

i think this will solve your problem